# How to convert negative svg path data to positive values?

Tags: dictionary, svg, r-maptools

I just created a Mercator projection of world map using mapping tool called [indiemapper](http://indiemapper.com/), and exported that map as SVG using that tool, right now Exported SVG’s path data is in negative points like this,

```
<path d="M -942472.5600891819 -1050000 L -942472.5600891819 -1050000 L -941430.5985257413 -1050000 L -940383.4009745446 -1050000 L -939336.203423348 -1050000 L -938289.0058721516 -1050000 L -937241.8083209549 -1050000 L -936194.6107697582 -1050000 L -935147.4132185617”>
```

If I use above path data to create map then the map goes out of view, Is there any why to convert that negative points to positive and make that map to fit into view?

Answer (score 1):

I take it you are reprocessing that SVG data into some other form?

Basically you need to transform the data the same way as the SVG file does.  Look at the transform attribute in the first  group:

```
transform="translate(400.5500464984095,309.74335472460336) scale(0.0002748297551314352)"
```

So it scales by 0.00027 and translates them to approx (400,309).  In other words it is shifting the origin to that point.

These transform commands will scale and reposition the data so that it fits inside the width and height specified in the root  element. That is 801x619.  If you want a different sized result, you will need to modify the transform operations approriately.

Comment: Note that the coordinates I specified above came from the test file I exported from indiemapper. Your file might be a bit different.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, i do saw that transform attribute is the one who bring the map into view, but the problem here is i'm not using any g tag for my paths and i'm not willing to set transform for each and every path, so is there any calculation to convert path data to fit into view.

Comment: Is there any tool to apply this transform to all paths or is there any way to make svg element to process this transform.

Comment: You would need to read every coordinate pair from the path definitions (`d` attributes) and apply a scaling calculation to each of them: `x = x * xScale + xCentre` `y = y * yScale + yCentre`.  You would need to experiment with the four scale and centre constants so that it is the size you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you multiply a number to -1 you will end up flipping it. ex: -10 x -1 = 10. I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but again this will not work because, 
-942472.5 * -1 = 942472.5 this point also goes out of view.